# How can I Optimize Spring Framework usage for Google App Engine Applications

Tags: java, spring, google-app-engine, spring-mvc

`Google App Engine` frontend instances are dynamically scaled. That means `App Engine` automatically creates new instances when load increases and turns off instances when they are not being used. Reloading instances may result in additional latency for users. Frontend instances also have a `60 seconds` deadline to complete a given request.

As I am using `Spring MVC and Spring IOC` in my GAE application, to Optimize Spring Framework usage, I have gone through [Best Practices for App Engine Applications](https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/spring_optimization).

In that link I am completely confused with the section **Reducing or Avoiding the Use of Relationship Autowiring** . It says `automatic wiring` can significantly the time required to resolve the beans during application initialization time, so they suggest autowire `byName` instead of using autowire `byType` .

So my question is How autowire `byName` reduces bean resolving time ?? . And also I would like to know is there any better way to inject beans ?. Is there any best practices for `Spring IOC` to reduce  application initialization time.

Comment: You can ignore Spring component scan, (and autowiring) and define all beans and their dependencies. So there will be no time needed for resolving dependencies, and I think using Java Config is easier to maintain than XML config.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let me give a reply to all the answers

> So my question is How autowire byName reduces bean resolving time ??

already explained by apurvc, in particular if you use interface or you use massive class inheritance **Spring will have to inspect the hierarchy of classes**

> I would like to know is there any better way to inject beans ?

1. Yes, do not inject bean by autowire but **use set or get property**, as
   you can; I use this policy.
2. **Avoid autoscan** component
3. Use **singleton** or bean pools or factory to reuse or construct object

> Is there any best practices for Spring IOC to reduce application
>   initialization time.

1. use lazy initialization (**@Lazy** annotation)
2. put not dependent bean **at the top** of XML definition

But you do not really need these solutions if you are JEE developer.

Answer (score 7):

Autowire "byType" obviously have to use some mechanism (and some processing )to correctly identify the bean whereas using "byName" provide a direct identification.

Take an analogy of a group of many breed of cats and dogs. To find the terrier out of the group you will have to first identify all breeds however when you use name of dogs it is much easier and improve the identification.

Spring does scanning of the classes for annotations which are inside package defined in "context:component-scan" if there are many classes in package it will take a while during start-up of an application hence it is suggested to use autowire byName.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. It is useful, could you also explain me, Is there any best practices for Spring IOC to reduce application initialization time, Specially i am looking  in terms of GAE . Thanks. I upvoted your answer as it is useful :).

Comment: I don't have much idea of GAE, for Spring you can narrow down the component scan by using include/exclude filters. This blog has many spring best practices http://gordondickens.com/wordpress/2012/07/30/enterprise-spring-framework-best-practices-part-3-xml-config/

Comment: I don't expect there's anything GAE specific about optimizing spring application startup time. It's just that GAE is interested in optimizing spring application startup time cause it scales the application performance by swapping in more cheap simple boxes when the load increases and they therefore have to initialize quickly.